# Rails Migration Decimal Column :default=> 0 re-setting MySQL precision to 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.0.3 (don't ask) and when I run a migration for table with decimal column and set :default => 0 it's re-setting the column's scale and precision to (10,0).

```
def self.up
 create_table :courses do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.string :name
  t.decimal :distance, :precision => 5, :scale => 2, :default => 0
  t.text :notes

  t.timestamps
 end
end
```

When I remove the :default=>0 option from the migration the column's scaled and precision are correct: (5,2)

I tried running a change_column migration with only :default =>: 0 set, but the column's scale and precision were re-set to (10,0)

```
change_column :courses, :distance, :decimal, :default => 0.0
```

I know I can go into MySQL and correct the precision and scale of the column, but wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug?

Google reveals no information so I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one: `t.decimal :distance, :precision => 5, :scale => 2, :default => 0.00`

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck on this one, and i cant find a solution to it. Eventually i had to go into mysql and change the required precision, scale and default value, i used this from [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1257) with a few modifications

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE question ADD (price INTEGER);
mysql> ALTER TABLE question DROP price;
mysql> ALTER TABLE question ADD (frig DECIMAL(5,2));
mysql> ALTER TABLE question CHANGE frig price DECIMAL(5,2);
mysql> ALTER TABLE question ALTER status SET DEFAULT '0';
mysql> ALTER TABLE question MODIFY price INTEGER;
```

Also try :default => 0.0 #note the 0.0 as the default value must be in the data type specified i.e. decimal

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What I ended up doing was removing the :precision and :scale options from the create_table migration and added a column_change migration for the column with :precision => 5 and :scale => 2. I left out the :default option. I rolled everything back, re-ran the migrations, and lo and behold MySQL had auto-magically set the column's default value to 0.0

Comment: @jacoulter no problem, i will definitely be using the method described by you next time i face this problem. I still do not understand why it has to be done this way, anyway as long as it works for now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
def change
    change_column :courses , :distance, :decimal, :precision => 5, :scale => 2, :null => false, :default => '0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying this right now and seems to work.

[Active Records Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

```
class ChangeVisitratioFormatInCampaigns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
        change_table :campaigns do |t|
            dir.up { t.change :visitratio, :decimal, :precision => 5, :scale => 4, :default => 1 }
            dir.down { t.change :visitratio, :integer }
        end
    end
  end
end
```